# How to inherit template struct operator()?

Tags: c++, templates

I try

```
template<class T>
struct getData
{
    boost::shared_ptr<T> operator()()
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<T>(new T());
    }
};

struct getVector : public getData<std::vector<int>>{};
```

I want to spesify `()` return via inheritence... but it seems to not return desired type. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is the exact problem? compile error? not doing what you expect?

Comment: Use the same syntax in derived class also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need the return type to be

```
boost::shared_ptr<T> operator()()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<T>(new T());
}
```